# Why can't I use the same wallet more than once in Plutus Playground?

Tags: plutus, plutus-playground, plutus-pab

I'm currently testing my app in the "Plutus Playground" and the simulation will not let me call an endpoint from the same contract more than once.

When I try to use the same wallet, the simulation does not register the call (as seen below).

[image]

[image: Only Tx 1 is registered, it does not hear the event for Tx 2]

Comment: have you tried adding a wait action after the second call? the emulated blockchain may take some slots to produce a new block